# Get current Payara MaxHeapSize and MetaspaceSize

Tags: payara

I have a running Payara 4 instance which I set the *MaxHeapSize* and *MetaspaceSize* as described [here](https://blog.payara.fish/fine-tuning-payara-server-in-production) to be production ready. How can I check those values were correctly set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this using `jmap -heap <pid>` on the PID of the Payara process. `jmap` is contained in the JDK `bin` directory.

On JDK9+ you need to use `jhsdb jmap --heap --pid <PID>` to get the needed information.

The output should contain the needed information, e.g:

```
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 268435456 (256.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 89128960 (85.0MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 89128960 (85.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 179306496 (171.0MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)
```